# print list content without duplicate

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list containing some contents like this:

```
numbers = [5,7,9,3,8]
```

I want to print consecutive elements starting with the first element and see output like this:

```
 5,7
 5,9
 5,3
 5,8
 7,9
 7,3
 7,8
 9,3
 9,8
 3,8
```

so, in the end, it will print elements without duplicating for any two elements

I have tried this

```
for e in numbers:
    print(numbers[:])
```

but it gave me

```
[5, 7, 9, 3, 8]
[5, 7, 9, 3, 8]
[5, 7, 9, 3, 8]
[5, 7, 9, 3, 8]
[5, 7, 9, 3, 8]
```

so how to solve this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [combinations from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> numbers = [5, 7, 9, 3, 8]
>>> list(combinations(numbers, 2))
[(5, 7), (5, 9), (5, 3), (5, 8), (7, 9), (7, 3), (7, 8), (9, 3), (9, 8), (3, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations

numbers = [5,7,9,3,8]
combos = combinations(numbers, 2)
for combo in combos:
    print(combo)

(5, 7)
(5, 9)
(5, 3)
(5, 8)
(7, 9)
(7, 3)
(7, 8)
(9, 3)
(9, 8)
(3, 8)
```